# Pasar un elemento de un Datagrid

Tags: c#

Hola buen día tengo una duda existencial, estoy llenando un `DataGrid` por medio de un `query` en **`C# windows forms`** , El cual me muestra en una columna varios `ID`, y por medio de la función `CellDoubleClick` en el DataGrid estoy mostrando una ventana en la que pretendo mostrar en un `Textbox` el numero del `ID` que seleccione desde el DataGrid solo que no recuerdo como pasar ese valor como un `parámetro` al nuevo `form` que es donde esta el `textbox`, alguien puede auxiliarme, estoy detenido en este momento. Dejo el código de como lo estoy haciendo.

**Form1**

```
       private void dgvInfoNomina_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                frmTimbraNomina objTimbrar = new frmTimbraNomina();
                objTimbrar.ShowDialog();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ex.ToString();
            }
        }
        public string EnviarId(string nomina)
        {           
            string IdNomina = "";
            IdNomina = dgvInfoNomina.CurrentCell.Value.ToString();
            return IdNomina;
        }
```

**Form2**

```
 public void MostrarId()
    {
        frmMuestraNomina objMostrar = new frmMuestraNomina();
        objMostrar.EnviarId()
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existen muchas formas de hacer esto. Dejaré una opción por pasos :

1. **`Crear una variable Publica`** en el `Form2` del tipo que se desee, en este caso `String`

   `public String valor;`
2. En el **`Load`** del `Form2` asignar el **`valor`** de la variable al `TextBox` deseado.

   ```
   private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       textBox1.Text = valor;
   }
   ```
3. En el `Form1` en el `Double_Click`, crear e `Instanciar` el `Form2`, para luego mediante esa instancia acceder a la variable valor que se creo y asignarle el `value` de la celda seleccionada.

   ```
   private void dgvInfoNomina_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
   {
   try
     {
       Form2 frm= new Form2();
       frm.valor = dgvInfoNomina.CurrentCell.Value.ToString();
       frm.ShowDialog();
     }
   catch (Exception ex)
     {
           ex.ToString();
     }
   ```

Comment: Gracias Amigo esta es la respuesta correcta, mil gracias por la ayuda, estaba completamente detenido, saludos y buen día.

Answer (score 1):

Supongo que quieres algo como esto:

```
private void dgvInfoNomina_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e){
int col_ID = 0; //suponiendo que el id se encuentre en la columna 0
string id = (string)dgvInfoNomina[e.RowIndex, col_ID].Value;
//Llamas a tu form y le pasas el id como parametro
}
```